# jQuery - div Animation: on mouse over, the other divs change their position

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I'm working on a jQuery animation that expands the height of a `div.panel` on mouse-in and contracts it back to normal on mouse-out.

The animation works for the selected `div.panel`, but the problem is relative at the nearby elements that moves down from their initial location when the mouse is over the `div.panel.panel-big`.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2zgXC/3/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume you want the `<li>`s to expand, not the entire `panel`. The problem is that you're selecting `.panel`, which applies to the whole thing.

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/r9XHr/)

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("li", this).hover(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            "height": "+=25px"
        }, "fast");
    }, function () {
        $(this).animate({
            "height": "-=25px"
        }, 300);
    });
});
```

Note the change from `$(".panel", this).hover(…)` to `$("li", this).hover(…`. This causes those pieces to properly expand/contract on mouse-in and mouse-out.

Tell me if this was not the intended behavior.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is not what I need.
I'm looking for the `.panel` height increment and decrement.

Comment: @RinoDrummer Could you explain in a little more depth (and add that description to your original question)? It really isn't clear what you want. What do you mean by "`.panel` height increment and decrement"?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in css, you have set the vertical align of the ".panel" to middle.
So when the ".panel-big" enlarges, the parent div (".row") also enlarges causing the panel-small to go down a little to remain centered vertically. Maybe you should set the vertical-align of the .panel to "top" and just put a margin-top for the panel-small.

```
.panel {
    color: #ffffff;
    margin: 10px 5px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 13pt;
    vertical-align: top;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.panel-small {
    background-color: #bfbfbf;
    width: 250px;
    height: 450px;
    max-height: 475px;
        margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Here is your fiddle which i tweaked:
http://jsfiddle.net/2zgXC/4/